# how to get the number of total posts in a wordpress category?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I want to show the number of posts in a category and replace that with "99" in my code.
this is my codes :

```html
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'filmview-menu', 'walker' => new wp_materialize_navwalker() ) ); ?>
```

```js
$('ul.menu-odd').each(function () {
    if ($(this).children().length > 4){
      $(this).addClass("two_cl");
   $(this).find('li > a').append('<span class="badge menu_num" data-badge-caption="(99)"></span>');
 }
   });
```

Comment: try this '<span class="badge menu_num" data-badge-caption="(99)">99 </span>'

Comment: there isn't a problem with this number. I want to replace the number of posts in that category with 99 or something else is there

Comment: show your html code for more understanding

Comment: To be clear, what you want is code to lie to the end user abut the number of posts in a specific category?

Comment: no, no, forget about that 99, this is my code : <span class="badge menu_num" data-badge-caption="here is the number of posts in the category"></span>

Answer (score 2):

```
$category = get_category($id);
$count = $category->category_count;
echo $count;
```

get the category by ID and save it in a variable. This variable is now that category object and it has a lot of associated information stored in it. Within the object array there will be the post count. It is called by using $category->category_count and saved as a variable that you can then echo anywhere after that.

Comment: Did you get any errors? Which part is not working? you can echo out at each stage to see where it is failing.

Comment: Here is a question that is the same as yours and has an accepted answer:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20973/count-how-many-posts-in-category

Comment: I get "print_r($category);"

Comment: okay, forget I mentioned that because it has been misunderstood. I have edit the question to have less information.

Comment: yes I knew that, and I forgot to say these are custom post types categories!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by simple WP_Query. And using `tax_query` for filtering based on custom taxonomy.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'YOUR_POST_TYPE',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'YOUR_CUSTOM_TAXONOMY',
            'field'    => 'slug', // Can also put 'term_id'
            'terms'    => 'bob',  // Custom taxonomy ID
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

And you get the total count by post_count variable,

```
<?php echo $query-> post_count; ?>
```

For more details on tax_query please check this out,

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Hope this one helps.